# JS to detect safari desktop not mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari

I'm trying to display different text based on particular rules. Here's what i need to achieve.

If the visitor is on:

**Desktop = Display message 1**

**Desktop but using safari = display Message 2 (NOT message 1)**

**Mobile = display message 3**

**Mobile & using safari (display message 3. NOT message 2)**

The route i was going down was this, however im really not a programmer, and other than detecting if the user is on safari ive got a little stuck! It needs to display on safari on desktops, but a different message on safari mobile. Ive looked around the forums, but nothing too similar is jumping out at me so I would really appreciate any help!:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() ||    isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) 
{document.writeln("<p>You're using safari!</p>");}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use same `navigator` object.

If you load you application in emulated mode and run navigator.userAgent

you may see this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

SO matching the word **Mobile** can help you to understand if it is a desktop or browser vesrion